# Integrity constraint violation while importing products in magento

Tags: magento, database-integrity

I am trying to import products in magento through a csv file.

I got this error while importing the file.

**please suggest me how resolve this error**

I got the following error

```
    SQLSTATE[23000]: **Integrity constraint violation: 1452** Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails
(`cataloginventory_stock_item`, CONSTRAINT
`FK_CATINV_STOCK_ITEM_PRD_ID_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ENTT_ID` FOREIGN KEY 
(`product_id`) REFERENCES `catalog_product_entity` (`entity_id`) ON DELETE
 CA)
```

Comment: the error is obvious , your CSV has a product id which is not there in catalog_product_entity table. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you CSV data file has some row(s) containing product id that doesn't exist in `catalog_product_entity`. Therefore it throws such exception. I think you need to verify product id value of imported CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar, found this thread so thought i'd post a resolution. If using the cataloginventory/stock_item model, note that you have to use loadByProduct() and not load():

The below will throw this exact error you have described, as you're trying to load a product, but its expecting a primary key for that table.

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->load($child['parent_id']);
```

Instead use:

```
Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($child['parent_id']);
```

Hope this helps someone!